# Wireless USB Print Server for use with both Linux and Windows

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, printer, network-printer

I am looking for a wireless usb print server that will work with my netbook running ubuntu and my main pc running windows.

There seems to be little information on anything that works with both reliability.

Dose anyone know of anything that will work?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [netgear WGPS606](http://www.netgear.co.uk/wireless_print_server_wgps606.php) wireless print server uses LDP protocol which is supported by Linux, windows and Mac.

Unlike older netgear print servers this print server works with multifunctional printers (for printing only) and there was a nice [compatibility list](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1093/kw/wgps606%20printer%20support/c/3/p/15%2C20%2C146%2C153%2C%2C/r_id/100109) on their website.

I am now successfully using this with my HP Photosmart C4272 on all my machines.